# Disabling Mercurial Hooks For Specific Repo Sources

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, mercurial-hook, hgrc, mercurial-extension

On my computer I have some [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) commit hooks that run on every commit that make sure I branch correctly and do a few other things. But I only need these for work projects.

**Here are the hooks implemented in my ~/.hgrc file:**

```
[hooks]
# This hook will warn you if you make a commit directly to trunk.
pretxncommit.default_check=/virtualhosts/mercurial-hooks/default_check.sh

# This hook will warn you if you branch from something other than default.
pretxncommit.branch_check=/virtualhosts/mercurial-hooks/branch_check.sh
```

For my personal projects I don't want to use the same, annoying hooks (which are set to global). I would like all of the repos I checkout from bitbucket to not use those hooks. How can I set it up to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `from_bitbucket.sh` that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
test -f $HG_PENDING/.hg/hgrc || exit 1
egrep -q 'default.*bitbucket\.org' $HG_PENDING/.hg/hgrc || exit 1
exit 0
```

Give the script execute permission (e.g., `chmod 755 from_bitbucket.sh`) and move it to whatever directory you want to keep it in permanently.

Change your hooks to something like:

```
pretxncommit.default_check=/path/to/from_bitbucket.sh || /virtualhosts/mercurial-hooks/default_check.sh
```

This will first execute `from_bitbucket.sh` and abort early with success if the script succeeds. The script checks only if there's a line matching `default.*bitbucket\.org` in your repository's `.hg/hgrc` file (which should generally exist in the `[paths]` section if you push to/pull from bitbucket). It will fail if there's no `.hg/hgrc` or if the file doesn't contain a matching line.